# Solr doesn't find synonym phrase despite correct working SynonymFilter

Tags: solr

Solr 4.3.0:

I want to enter "Basel 3" in the Solr-searchfield and want to get all results for either "Basel 3" or "Basel III". I'm on the right way, because the analyzer shows a match with this query:

```
http://localhost/solr/analysis/field?analysis.fieldvalue=Basel III&q=Basel:3&analysis.fieldname=description&analysis.showmatch=true
```

Also a result of the search for "Basel 3" shows a correct highlighting of "Basel III", which happen to be in the same result.
But, and that's my problem now, all the results containing only "Basel III" are missing.

schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="2" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="2" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

synonyms.txt:

```
Basel 3, Basel III
```

"toggle parsed query" shows:

```
(+DisjunctionMaxQuery((title:"(basel basel 3) 3"^2.5 | recruiter:basel 3^1.5 | description:"(basel basel 3) 3"^0.5)))/no_coord
```

**EDIT**: 
There seems to be a whole family of open issues around "multiword synonyms":
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2605
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-1622
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4381
(...)

A very interesting article about this subject: http://nolanlawson.com/2012/10/31/better-synonym-handling-in-solr/